# Find Possible addition combinations in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, array-algorithms

What is the best way to approach this problem? I have no idea on how to start. This is not a homework problem, but rather practice for interviews.

'Using the JavaScript language, have the function ArrayAddition(arr) take the array of numbers stored in arr and return the string true if any combination of numbers in the array can be added up to equal the largest number in the array, otherwise return the string false. For example: if arr contains [4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3] the output should return true because 4 + 6 + 10 + 3 = 23. The array will not be empty, will not contain all the same elements, and may contain negative numbers. '

http://coderbyte.com/CodingArea/GuestEditor.php?ct=Array%20Addition&lan=JavaScript

Comment: The "string true" and the "string false"? Uh oh.

Comment: The combination consisting of just the largest number in the array is always a solution. Is there a typo in the question?

Comment: Not always - there are some combinations that might not add up to the largest element number. Take a look at the link and example inputs.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Dear mister bestprogrammerintheworld, please read the question more carefully next time. Your answer is not correct, maybe you should be called mostlazyprogrammerintheworld (I'm just kidding obviously)? -- Edit, I'm not one to talk BTW, I made two typos and misspelled your name lol.

Comment: @ShellFish - sorry. I was to much in a hurry. I aplogize for that :-)

Comment: @ user1027217, he means the largest number of the array itself (added with nothing) satisfies the requirements. There is indeed always a solution because the largest added with nothing equals the largest number and it is contained in the array so in fact the answer is simply "echo true", but then in javascript.

Comment: @ShellFish - well, we're getting into semantics; i just assumed the largest value in the array should not be included.

Comment: What did you try ? If it took more than 10 minutes to solve this, i suggest rather you apply for another job.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: "any combinations of numbers" to me states that it can not be a single number. But I wouldn't exclude the largest number since some of the values might cancel each other out. So for `[1,2,-1,23]` -> 1 + -1 + 23 = 23

Comment: @GameAlchemist :cough ***hole :cough

Comment: Hint: the binary representations of the numbers *0* through *2^n - 1* encode all possible subsets of a *n* element set. As @Bergi points out, it's an NP-complete problem so they can't be expecting anything efficient. That's not to say you can't do some pretty clever things to improve the exponent of the runtime, but try getting a brute-force answer out first. Edit: and this is assuming "echo true" isn't an acceptable answer.

Comment: This looks like the knapsack problem, and I doubt anyone is expecting you to come up with a solution in ten minutes during a job interview, I would be impressed if a candidate was even able to recognize it as "knapsack" or NP ?

Comment: @AndyJones You can expect a pseudo-polynomial solution though. If the numbers are bounded, it's easy to solve efficiently

Comment: @adeneo I think if you are familiar with basic theoretical computer science it's very easy to detect a subset sum application and coding at least the 2^n algorithm in well under 10 minutes (note that SS is somewhat simpler than Knapsack). The pseudopolynomial DP algorithm is also very simple, the only problem here is the negative numbers, which require a bit of thinking (but not too much). I've been asked much harder questions than this in interviews

Comment: @NiklasB. If there was a reasonable bound on the inputs yeah the DP approach would be much superior. If it was an actual interview then that'd be an important ambiguity to resolve. Unfortunately in this case we can't answer that question, and JS's one numeric type (`Number`) is a double under the hood, so while the DP approach would technically work in *O(N^2)* time, there's a pretty huge hidden constant.

Comment: @AndyJones In fact it would work in O((B-A)*N) where A and B are the min and max of the array, respecitively. But of course with floating point, all hope is lost. There's also a nice O(2^(n/2)) meet-in-the middle algorithm which works with arbitrary values

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. For this code i use this reference [github](https://gist.github.com/axelpale/3118596).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var bol=false
var arr=[4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3]
var maxx=Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
var index = arr.indexOf(maxx);
arr.splice(index, 1);


function k_combinations(set, k) {
    var i, j, combs, head, tailcombs;
    if (k > set.length || k <= 0) {
        return [];
    }
    if (k == set.length) {
        return [set];
    }
    if (k == 1) {
        combs = [];
        for (i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
        combs.push([set[i]]);
    }
    return combs;
    }
    combs = [];
    for (i = 0; i < set.length - k + 1; i++) {
        head = set.slice(i, i+1);
        tailcombs = k_combinations(set.slice(i + 1), k - 1);
        for (j = 0; j < tailcombs.length; j++) {
            combs.push(head.concat(tailcombs[j]));
        }
    }
    return combs;
}


function combinations(set) {
    var k, i, combs, k_combs;
    combs = [];
    for (k = 1; k <= set.length; k++) {
        k_combs = k_combinations(set, k);
        for (i = 0; i < k_combs.length; i++) {
            combs.push(k_combs[i]);
      }
    }
    return combs;
}
var result=combinations(arr)


for(z=0;z<result.length;z++){
    var tot=0
    for(c=0;c<result[z].length;c++){
        tot+=result[z][c]
    }
    if(tot===maxx){bol=true}
}

console.log(bol)


</script>
```

If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.

Comment: @chando I disagree that sorting(!) is a better way to find the maximum of an array. In fact I would say it's a *worse* way because it's slower (linearithmic vs. linear time). The next time please consider writing a comment instead of modifying other people's code

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. For combinations code I have used this reference [github](https://gist.github.com/jpillora/4435759)

```
<script>
function algorithem() {    
        var arr = [4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3];
        arr.sort(function(a,b) { return a-b } );
        var largest = arr[arr.length-1];
        arr.pop();

         function combinations(set) {
          return (function acc(xs, set) {
            var x = xs[0];
            if(typeof x === "undefined")
              return set;
            for(var i = 0, l = set.length; i < l; ++i)
              set.push(set[i].concat(x));
            return acc(xs.slice(1), set);
          })(set, [[]]).slice(1);
        };

        function add(arr) {
                   var sum = 0;
                var len = arr.length;
              for( var j=0;j<len;j++){
                    var p = arr[j];
                    for(var i=0,sum=0; i<p.length;i++){
                        sum += p[i];
                        if(largest == sum){
                            return true;

                        }
                    }
              };
              if( j == len){return false;}
        }
        add(combinations(arr));
    };
   </script>
```

Comment: How does this use jQuery? Including that seems totally useless.

Comment: `forEach` does not break on returning false?

Comment: What does the `try catch` do there? Why are `i`, `j` and `matched` global variables? WTH do you `break` after `return`ing? What do you need `matched` for at all? And why is that last `return` inside a condition?

Comment: I am trying to break the outer loop when the largest number is equals sum of the combinations of array for this break and return matched with in condition and if any of the combinations of array elements sum is not equals largest number it returns the false this is what outer loop does.

Comment: But why don't you just `return` from the function?